# Divergence theorem to calculate the flux

Tags: real-analysis

I have the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,z^2)$ and i want to find the flux through the part of the cone $\{z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$ between the planes $z=1$ and $z=2$. How do I use the divergence theorem here?

I thought that i must add two surfaces at the top and bottom to get a closed surface, but further I don't know what to do

Comment: You're on the right track. Calculate the total flux using the divergence theorem, calculate the flux through those top and bottom surfaces, and substract the latter from the former.

Comment: @zuggg But what are those fluxes? How do i find them?

Comment: The top surface is the disk of equation $S^+:z=2, x^2+y^2\leq z^2=4$. The outward poiting unit vector is simply $(0,0,1)$, hence the flux through this surface is, by definition, $\int_{S^+} (-x,-y,z^2)\cdot (0,0,1) dS= \int_{S^+} 4 dS = 4\cdot 4\pi$.

Use the same strategy to get the flux though the bottom surface.

Comment: @zuggg Why is $\int_{S+}4dS=4\cdot 4\pi$? And is the bottom flux then $-4\pi$?

Comment: Because $\int_{S^+}dS$ is simply the area of the disk $S^+$, which radius is $z=2$, so $\int_{S^+}dS=z^2\pi=4\pi$. The flux through the bottom surface is then $\int_{S^-} 1dS = -\pi$, because $S^-$ is a disk of radius 1, not 2.

Comment: Okay, and what is the total flux then? I know that the divergence of F is $2z-2$, but what should i integrate then?

Comment: The total flux is then given by $\int_V \operatorname{div}(F)dV$, where $V$ is given by $V=\{(x,y,z)\mid z\in[1,2], x^2+y^2\leq z^2\}$. Notice that the divergence is independent from $x,y$, so you can easily integrate with respect to those variables first, and then integrate with respect to $z$.

Comment: @zuggg So i integrate $z$ from $1$ to $2$, but what are then my boundaries for $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S^+$ be the disk of equation $S^+:z=2, x^2+y^2\leq z^2$, and similarly, $S^-:z=1, x^2+y^2\leq z^2$. Let $S$ be the part of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2, z\in[1,2]$, and $V$ the volume between those surfaces, i.e. $V=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\leq z^2, z\in[1,2]\}$.

The divergence theorem gives
$$
\int_{S\cup S^+\cup S^-}\vec F\cdot\vec \nu dS= \int_V\operatorname{div}(\vec F)dV
$$
where $\vec \nu$ is the outward pointing unit vector. We then write
$$
\int_S\vec F\cdot\vec \nu dS= \int_V\operatorname{div}(\vec F)dV-\int_{S^-}\vec F\cdot\vec \nu dS-\int_{S^+}\vec F\cdot\vec \nu dS.
$$

For any point $(x,y,z)\in S^+$, $\vec\nu=(0,0,1)$, so
$$
\int_{S^+}\vec F\cdot\vec \nu dS=\int_{S^+} z^2dS = z^2\cdot \pi z^2 = 16\pi
$$
since $z$ is constant throughout $S^+$. Likewise, 
$$
\int_{S^-}\vec F\cdot\vec \nu dS=-z^4\pi=-\pi
$$

Finally, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \int_V \operatorname{div}(\vec F)dV &= \int_V (-2+2z) dxdydz \\
    &=\int_{z=1}^{z=2}\left(\int_{x^2+y^2\leq z^2}(-2+2z) dxdy\right)dz\\
    &=\int_1^2 (-2+2z)\left(\int_{x^2+y^2\leq z^2}dxdy\right)dz\\
    &=\int_1^2 (-2+2z)\pi z^2 dz\\
    &=2\pi\left[-z^3/3 + z^4/4\right]_1^2\\
    &=17\pi /6
\end{aligned}
$$
and the flux we were looking for is
$$
\int_S\vec F\cdot\vec \nu dS=\pi(17/6+1-16)=-73\pi/6.
$$